# please explain this definition of neighborhood in graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

$$N(A) = \bigcup_{v\in A} N(v)$$

$v$ is a vertex in $G(V,E)$ graph. $A$ is a subset of $V$. In my book, it is defined as

> "If $A$ is a subset of $V$, we denote by $N(A)$ the set of all vertices
>   in $G$ that are adjacent to at least one vertex in $A$"
>
> -Referenced from Discrete mathematics and its applications (7th ed.) by Rosen, K. (2012).

I can understand the definition of the sentence. But I cannot understand the equation. Please explain by breaking the equation down if it is possible.

Comment: The equation says: The neighborhod of a graph is the union of the neighborhoods of all the vertices of the graph.  In other to get the neighborhood of a big honking giant graph you take each of its vertices and note all the vertices that are adjecent to it.  Do this for each vertex in the graph and you will get all the vertices in the neighborhood.

Comment: Take a vertex $a$ of $A.$ Then collect all the vertices adjacent to $a.$ This is the set $N(a).$ Do the same thing for all $a\in A.$ Now take the union of all such  sets ($\cup N(a)$)

Answer (score 1):

$N(v)$ denotes the neighbors of a vertex $v$.

Each vertex $v$ in $A$ has its own set of neighbors $N(v)$.

If a vertex is a neighbor of at least one vertex $v$ in $A$, then it belongs to at least one of these $N(v)$. So we take the union of all these neighbor sets $N(v)$ over all vertices $v \in A$.

For example, if $A=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, then the neighbor sets of each vertex are $N(v_1)$, $N(v_2)$ and $N(v_3)$, and we define $N(A)$ as $\bigcup_{v \in A} N(v) := N(v_1) \cup N(v_2) \cup N(v_3)$.

Comment: Nice explanation. Got it. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is saying that the neighborhood of $A$ is just the union of all the neighborhoods of vertices in $A$. The index on the union symbol just means to take the union over all vertices in $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The author is using $N(v)$ to denote the set of all vertices which are connected to $v$ by an edge (i.e., the set of all neighboring vertices).  In an equation:
$$ N(v)=\{w\in V\mid (v,w)\textrm{ is an edge}\}$$

From this, the validity of the equation is easy to see.